# how can i mod_rewrite this?

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
mydomain.com/dir/cgi-bin/mirror.cgi/http/www.test.com/
```

into

```
mydomain.com/www.test.com
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which parts of the input vary? Just the 'test' from www.test.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .htaccess file:

```
ModRewrite On
RewriteRule (([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}) /dir/cgi-bin/mirror.cgi/http/$1/
```

Regex pulled from [regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=391).

The first half defines a regular expression that matches valid domain names, and the second part is what it is redirected to (with `$1` replaced by the matching domain).

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^www\.[^/]+$ /dir/cgi-bin/mirror.cgi/http/$0/
```

That will rewrite a request of `/www.example.com` internally to `/dir/cgi-bin/mirror.cgi/http/www.example.com/`.